# くれる, あげる, and もらう

Tags: grammar

Which pair is correct?

## A

> 父がお正月に一万円**あげました**。私は今までに、こんなにたくさん**もらった**ことがなかったので、とてもうれしかったです。

## B

> 父がお正月に一万円**くれました**。私は今までに、こんなにたくさん**くれた**ことがなかったので、とてもうれしかったです。

Comment: 父がお正月に一万円あげました = My father gave Yen 10,000 to someone (other than me).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither pair is correct.

Correct pair:

「(From B) **父が**お正月に一万円**くれました**。(From A) **私は**今までに、こんなにたくさん**もらった**ことがなかったので、とてもうれしかったです。」

The sentence patterns that are at work here are:

> 「**2nd/3rd Person** + は/が + 1st Person + に + (Object) + を + **くれる**」
>
> 「1st Person + は/が + 2nd/3rd Person + に + (Object) + を + **もらう**」

Also correct though not applicable with your example:

> 「2nd Person + は/が + 1st/3rd Person + に + (Object) + を + **もらう**」,
>
> 「3rd Person + は/が + 1st/2nd/Another 3rd Person + に + (Object) + を + **もらう**」, etc.

I will stop here as a complete list using all three verbs will only confuse users (as well as myself).

Comment: （あなた/かれ）が私にお金をもらった。I think it is ungrammatical.

Comment: @Friendly Ghost; In Japanese, any verbs can be grammatically applied to any grammatical persons.

Comment: @Friendly Ghost: It sure sounds bizarre, but it is not ungrammatical. I can't come up with a good example, but let me have a try: we all know that "the sun sets in the east" is incorrect (semantically wrong), but *syntactically* the statement is without flaw.

Comment: I've just come up with one; なるほど、私に もらって うれしかったわけか: "I see, so you were glad that you got it from me".