# Relative and passive and how to parse sentences

Tags: grammar, passive-voice, relative-clauses, parsing

Is a relative possible with the passive form?

> 誰もが残された時間を、駆け抜けて、過ぎていく。

Is this indirect passive? How would I make 誰もが残された時間 not relative?

> 誰もが残された時間
>
> 誰もが時間を残された

I also would like to add another question because it seems I am lost. I thought in Japanese what comes before a verb refers to it, then that verb modifies a noun that comes after it.

For example:

> 僕が彼にくれたペンで書いた手紙をメールで彼女に届いた。
>
> [[僕が彼にくれた]ペンで書いた]手紙をメールで彼女に届いた。

In this example 僕が彼にくれた modifies ペン and 僕が彼にくれたペンで書いた modifies 手紙. Am I wrong?

I really do not understand what modifies what in Japanese apparently -- my previous idea doesn't work with sentences like the original example. Could somebody explain this to me?

Comment: 「誰もが」は、「駆け抜けて・・・」の主語かも。。。？

Comment: I tought it was: [誰もが(は)残された]>時間を駆け抜けて過ぎていく。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's 誰もが駆け抜けて過ぎていく ("everyone rushes away and goes past"), and 残された時間 ("time left") is [where it happens](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/21313/5010). 誰もが時間を残された makes little sense unless [迷惑の受け身](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/1777/5010) is intended, and the noun clause 誰もが残された時間 also makes little or no sense to me. The normal way to say "time left for everyone" is 誰も**に**残された時間. (eg 私に残された時間は少ない。 = There is little time left for me.)

As for the other question, first, 手紙を届いた is ungrammatical because 届く is intransitive. 届ける is the transitive counterpart. [僕が彼にくれた sounds strange](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/25535/5010) too, and this part should be either 僕が彼に**あげた**ペン (the pen I gave to him) or **彼が僕に**くれたペン (the pen he gave to me). Oh, and you should use 郵便 instead of メール, because メール usually refers to emails.

> 彼が僕にくれたペンで書いた手紙を郵便で彼女に届けた。

Now this sentence is simple to me. As you suggest, 彼に僕にくれた modifies ペン and 彼が僕にくれたペンで書いた modifies 手紙.

Comment: Thanks for the corrections. What I don't get is why it's 誰もが[残された>時間]を、駆け抜けて、過ぎていく。 and not [誰もが残された]>時間を、駆け抜けて、過ぎていく。It's because it's a passive verb? Or else how do I know when a case like this happen?

Comment: Well, 私が残された島 means "the island where I was left", so in a sci-fi novel, 誰もが残された時間 might technically mean something like "the time where everyone is left alone", but I just couldn't think of such a bizarre interpretation. We say "time is left", but not "I was left in a time".

Comment: Well the author tends to be kind of poetic in its own way. One other questions. When making a relative clause is it there a rule to what modifies what? The normal rule I think is that whatever comes before a noun refers to it right?

Comment: Yes you know the general rule, but the modified noun does not always comes *directly* after the relative clause. "僕が昨日食べた子供が作った料理" is technically ambiguous, but there is only one sane interpretation.

Comment: I laughed reading your sentence. Btw after all is all about ambiguity right?
Maybe I need to increase my vocabolary